# SQL Join based on three keys

Tags: join, teradata

Database is Teradata

I have two table which I am trying to join. Following are the table structures. When I join these table I expect to get two rows as output but getting 4 rows.what is reason for this behavior. Join based on three keys should uniquely identify a row but still getting 4 rows as output. Any help is appreciated.

```
TableA
Weekkey|segment|type|users
201501|1|A|100
201501|1|B|100
TableB
Weekkey|segment|type|revenue
201501|1|A|200
201501|1|B|200
```

when I join these two table using the following query i get the following result

```
select a.* ,b.user
from tablea a left join  tableb b on a.weekkey=b.weekkey 
and  a.segment=b.segment
and  a.type=b.type

Weekkey|segment|type|revenue|users
201501|1|A|200|100
201501|1|B|200|100
201501|1|A|200|100
201501|1|B|200|100
```

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: Using sql server and the data and query you posted the output isn't possible.

Comment: I asume (by looking at the table names) that this is an example query. You sure you didn't reuse an alias? Like:  a.type = a.type

Comment: Also, according to your sample data, your `users` column is in TableA whereas your query says otherwise.

Comment: Database is terdata. I am not using any repeated alias.

Comment: This query works.Is this teradata specific behavior? select a.* ,b.user
from tablea a left join  tableb b on a.weekkey|| a.segment||a.type=b.weekkey|| b.segment||b.type

Comment: Please show your actual query, `type` and `user` are reserved keywords in Teradata, so your query will not run.

Answer (score 1):

Using sql server, here is ddl and sample data along with the query you posted. The output you state you are getting doesn't happen here.

```
create table #tablea
(
    Weekkey int
    , segment int
    , type char(1)
    , users int
)

insert #tablea
select 201501, 1, 'A', 100 union all
select 201501, 1, 'B', 100

create table #TableB
(
    Weekkey int
    , segment int
    , type char(1)
    , revenue int
)
insert #TableB
select 201501, 1, 'A', 200 union all
select 201501, 1, 'B', 200

select a.* 
    , b.revenue
from #tablea a 
left join #tableb b on a.weekkey = b.weekkey 
and a.segment = b.segment
and a.type = b.type

drop table #tablea
drop table #TableB
```

Comment: Database is terdata. When i contact all the three keys and join I don't get the duplication

Comment: This query works.Is this teradata specific behavior? select a.* ,b.user from tablea a left join tableb b on a.weekkey|| a.segment||a.type=b.weekkey|| b.segment||b.type

Comment: You tagged your question with several DBMS. As I said in my post this is for sql server.